# USB camera Genus Eye 312 not working in motion 4.3.1 and ffplay

Tags: usb, camera

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on my laptop.
I have motion 4.3.1 installed and working well with  laptop integrated camera .
But with outside USB camera Genuis Eye 312  ( Vendor ID 093a Pixart inc.)  it is not working .
What I understand no proper codec and pixel format.
Is there  some way to make this camera work in motion?

This  is I get in terminal :

```
$ ffplay /dev/video0
ffplay version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright © 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil 56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec 58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat 58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice 58. 8.100 / 58. 8.100
libavfilter 7. 57.100 / 7. 57.100
libavresample 4. 0. 0 / 4. 0. 0
libswscale 5. 5.100 / 5. 5.100
libswresample 3. 5.100 / 3. 5.100
libpostproc 55. 5.100 / 55. 5.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7fbeac000bc0] Cannot find a proper format for codec ‘none’ (id 0), pixel format ‘none’ (id -1)
Assertion *codec_id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at src/libavdevice/v4l2.c:815
Aborted (core dumped)
joso@joso-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ /) v4+ to run.
```